# How can i get a result of a .some()?

Tags: typescript

I need to get one field of a array.

I have a .some() function to find if the array contains a field that is equal to another one.

`this.entity.entityEdic.some(r=> r.entityEdicId == this.entEdic.entityEdicId)`

If the result is TRUE, i want to get the "r.id" from the array. have a simple way to do this?

Comment: What you want is [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some` only returns true of false, you can use `find` function instead. It returns the matched entity or `undefined`

```
let entity = this.entity.entityEdic.find(
   r => r.entityEdicId == this.entEdic.entityEdicId 
);

if(entity != undefined) {
   ___ do something with this entity ___
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are just returning the comparison result.
You have to surrounded your anonymous function with curley braces to extend the code.

```
this.entity.entityEdic.some(r => {
    if(r.entityEdicId === this.entEdic.entityEdicId) {
        return r.id;
 })
```

As you are not using any type checking, this can be called javascript code rather than typescript.

Comment: This is just plain wrong, the resulting value will depend on whether some `r.id` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: I am unclear about the question, the question needs to be broadened. I assumed .some() function finds the matching array and OP wants to return the value if the comparison is true.